# How to suppress qqPlot() from showing the indices of outliers?

Tags: r, r-markdown, outliers, qqplot

Simple question, but I couldn't find a solution. I am creating a normal probability plot using qqPlot() in Rmarkdown, and I am getting these annoying vectors in my report which are showing the indices of the two outliers, and I don't know how to get rid of them. Does anyone know which argument can suppress the display of outlier indices?"

Comment: Use `id = FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I don't know how to mark your comment as the answer.

Comment: You can't do that, but you can answer your own question if you want to fill it out into a full answer.  You should include some reproducible demo code.